# Route planning on line segments which can be connected or not

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, graph-traversal

[image]

I have several lines that are shown in different colours, do not know which are connected to each other in advance. I want to do path planning only using these lines, i.e., route planning. If I am able to construct a graph using these line segments, I can use graph search techniques, e.g., A*, to find the path between provided two start and target points.

**Quation**:
What could be the optimal way to construct a graph using these line segments? Each such line segment consists of a set of points along the line.

After @Yves Daoust suggestion I got want I want, many tanks

[image]

Comment: Optimal in what sense ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Possible first steps are binarization, then thinning.

[image]

After that, it is no big deal to find the junctions and to follow the edges between them.

---

A piece of caution: thinning tends to turn the lane crossings to double junction points instead of a single. These configurations can be a little tricky to handle.

Comment: Thank youu, I will consider this way :)